# dependency injection not behaving in spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Simply I have 2 classes. Questions.java and Answers.java
I am just trying to inject answers object into Questions.
This is my beans.xml file

```
<bean id="questions" class="main.Questions">
    <constructor-arg value="0000"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="What is the question?"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="threading"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="correctAnswer" value="deadlock"></property>
    <property name="answers" ref="answers"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="answers" class="main.Answers">
<constructor-arg value="0000"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="LiveLock"></constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

When i output to the console in netbeans i just get this line

```
Question [questionId=0, question=What is the question?, category=threading, correctAnswer=deadlock]
```

when surely i should get answers=answers injected into it.
literally have no idea why this wont work.

Comment: What about using <property name="" value=""/> instead of constructor-arg and setters?

Comment: Do you have answers in your toString?

Comment: @almasshaikh I am just getting this so far
Question [questionId=0, question=What is the question?, category=threading, correctAnswer=deadlock]

Comment: @Emilio - I probably will but 1) surely that is not breaking it? and 2) I am still new to Spring and so wanted to test out different options to see how they work. if you get me

Comment: ........solved.......thanks for the help anyway. can you guys tick my answer so everyone can see it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]. foolish error, just forgot to put the correct stuff in the toString() method. apologies for a horrible error everyone!